# Bumblebee running on Nvidia does not increase performance

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

When I run anything with bumblebee it doesn't provide performance increase compared to running on the Intel integrated chip. Is this an indication of incorrectly installed drivers and settings or just drivers not working properly yet?

My Nvidia cars shows in `lspci` as:

```
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev ff)
```

I have installed newest nvidia drivers (nvidia-337) and configured `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` according to instructions like on [this site](http://www.muktware.com/2013/12/install-nvidia-331-bumblebee-optimus-cards/18271) to use the drivers.
The card seems to be detected by bumblebee without any problems.

Following output from few example runs of `glxspheres64`:

```
anezka@redquark ~ $ vblank_mode=0 glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
173.431794 frames/sec - 154.409795 Mpixels/sec
149.875149 frames/sec - 133.436843 Mpixels/sec
148.822554 frames/sec - 132.499696 Mpixels/sec
149.262262 frames/sec - 132.891177 Mpixels/sec
anezka@redquark ~ $ vblank_mode=0 optirun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 730M/PCIe/SSE2
83.187336 frames/sec - 74.063349 Mpixels/sec
85.823322 frames/sec - 76.410220 Mpixels/sec
84.681689 frames/sec - 75.393802 Mpixels/sec
86.131217 frames/sec - 76.684345 Mpixels/sec
anezka@redquark ~ $ vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxspheres64
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Polygons in scene: 62464
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 730M/PCIe/SSE2
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
107.977603 frames/sec - 96.134619 Mpixels/sec
108.357600 frames/sec - 96.472939 Mpixels/sec
108.341271 frames/sec - 96.458401 Mpixels/sec
108.348674 frames/sec - 96.464992 Mpixels/sec
```

I am using Mint 16 - Petra; most packages for this are taken from Ubuntu Saucy

Comment: please improve: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: If you don't get anything useful here, I'd contact the devs directly. They are very responsive.

Comment: I added the version I am using. @Sparhawk Thanks for the suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by this myself. The Bumblebee FAQ says, that it makes little sense to use the glxspheares output because of something about VirtualGL. I don't understand the issue, but so they say.

Check here: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ#how-to-check-nvidia-card-performances--they-seems-low

If someone who has deeper knowledge in this could elaborate I'd be really happy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Just delete Bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

And then just say "hello!" to Nvidia-Prime

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

After selecting your graphic card from nvidia-settings, (intel or nvidia)

you should log out and come back. (Unfortunately after every changes)