# Nvidia Drivers break several hot-keys on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, nvidia-optimus

I have a ThinkPad W530, which has Optimus. When I am running the NVidia card with Nouveau or the Intel integrated card with Intel drivers, the Microphone mute, ThinkVantage key, and brightness works fine. When I switch to NVidia-prime with the NVidia Proprietary drivers, all three of those functions stop working.

I have been unable to fix it so far. Are there any resolutions for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! you find this useful: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. I managed to get the brightness working again, but the microphone mute and thinkvantage key are completely gone from xev and showkey

Answer (score 1):

Clean installing Ubuntu trusty, installing all the updates, then installing bumblebee seems to have solved the problem.

nvidia-prime must have been causing the x not starting issues, and now bumblebee is working, so I can use my nvidia and still have my hotkeys.

Comment: Please improve your answer by breaking it down step by step so that others with your problem can benefit (and upvote your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Switch back to running the NVidia card with Nouveau or the Intel integrated card with Intel drivers, for as you state when you do so "the Microphone mute, ThinkVantage key, and brightness all work fine."

Comment: Going to attempt to use acpi_listen to see if the buttons give a response there.

Comment: Does using Bumblebee have any effect?

Comment: X doesn't want to start properly when bumblebee(or the nvidia-prime) things are enabled.

Comment: aaaaand, after clean installing Ubuntu trusty, installing all the updates, then installing bumblebee, everything seems to be operational. strange. It seems that nvidia-prime was the problem with X starting.

Comment: Congratulations. I'm glad you got it sorted.

Comment: thanks!! although for some reason, I get the same performance with and without optirun.

Comment: There is a question here regarding that. You may wish to follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/454354/bumblebee-running-on-nvidia-does-not-increase-performance